# PHP. Issues with Wamp and xml for nusoap client call

Tags: php, xml, nusoap

I am working on a nusoap client call, for a web service, I am using nusoap.php last library.

When I made the XML structure I use this:

```
$string =<<<XML<?xml version='1.0'?><cliente>
    <nombre>$posts['nombre']</nombre>
    <apellido>$posts['apellido']</apellido>
    <calle>$posts['direccion']</calle>
    <altura>$posts['altura']</altura>
    <pisodto>$posts['pisodto']</pisodto>
    <localidad>$posts['localidad']</localidad>
    <provincia>$posts['provincia']</provincia>
    <partido>$posts['partido']</partido>
    <telefono>$posts['telefono']</telefono>
    <celular>$posts['celular']</celular>
    <email>$posts['email']</email>
</cliente>
XML;
```

But for some reason WAMP doesn't like it and I always get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in G:\wamp\www\bsmart\PHPtoXML2\enviarxml.php on line 98

Here is the full code

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires');
require_once 'assets/clases/nusoap/nusoap.php';   
$wsdl = "http://ws.maxirest.com/wsclientes/wscli06896.php?WSDL";
$cliente = new nusoap_client($wsdl);
$produccion = false; //Cambiar a verdadero por producction
$endpoint = $wsdl;

//print_r($_POST);

$posts = $_POST;

if ($produccion == false) {
    $posts['nombre'] =
        $posts['apellido'] =
            $posts['direccion'] =
                    $posts['pisodto'] =
                        $posts['localidad'] =
                            $posts['partido'] =
                                $posts['provincia'] =
                                    $posts['telefono'] =
                                        $posts['celular'] =
                                            $posts['altura'] =
                                                $posts['email'] =
                                                            "PRUEBA";
}


$string =<<<XML<?xml version='1.0'?><cliente>
    <nombre>$posts['nombre']</nombre>
    <apellido>$posts['apellido']</apellido>
    <calle>$posts['direccion']</calle>
    <altura>$posts['altura']</altura>
    <pisodto>$posts['pisodto']</pisodto>
    <localidad>$posts['localidad']</localidad>
    <provincia>$posts['provincia']</provincia>
    <partido>$posts['partido']</partido>
    <telefono>$posts['telefono']</telefono>
    <celular>$posts['celular']</celular>
    <email>$posts['email']</email>
</cliente>
XML;

$param = array('cXml' => $string, 'clave' => "123ClubMilaMREST5");

$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl);//Ruta donde se encuentra nuestro servicio para consumirlo

$resultado = $client->call('AltaSolicitud',$param);

//Codigo para debugear y ver la respuesta y posibles errores, comentar cuando se comprueba que está correcto el servicio y la llamada
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<p><b>Constructor error: ' . $err . '</b></p>';
}
echo '<h2>Request</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</b></p>';
echo '<p><b>Debug: <br>';
echo htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) .'</b></p>';
//Comentar hasta aquí

if($client->fault)
{
    echo "FAULT: <p>Code: (".$client->faultcode.")</p>";
    echo "String: ".$client->faultstring;
}
else
{
    var_dump ($resultado);
}
```

I think maybe a library could be missing, but I am not sure, any help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually that just a PHP syntax error so its not the fault of WAMPServer, its a typo

Comment: That, and the `$posts` variable chaining like that is wrong.

Comment: *Not the type of RAILS, we was lookin' for, eh Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: @JayBlanchard Why is the `$posts` chaining wrong. That should set all to `PRUEBA` I know its nonsence as in that code `$produccion` will always be == false but?

Comment: Yes, you're right @RiggsFolly but I don't think the OP wants to set them all the same. Do you?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Oh I see, no i doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a line-break after XML.

```
$string = <<<XML
                ^
 line break mandatory, it marks the end of the "XML" mark (heredoc identifier).
```

See the [PHP Heredoc String Syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for the important details.

Additionally array string keys *inside* strings aren't quoted.

Full example:

```
$string = <<<XML
    <?xml version='1.0'?><cliente>
    <nombre>$posts[nombre]</nombre>
    <apellido>$posts[apellido]</apellido>
    <calle>$posts[direccion]</calle>
    <altura>$posts[altura]</altura>
    <pisodto>$posts[pisodto]</pisodto>
    <localidad>$posts[localidad]</localidad>
    <provincia>$posts[provincia]</provincia>
    <partido>$posts[partido]</partido>
    <telefono>$posts[telefono]</telefono>
    <celular>$posts[celular]</celular>
    <email>$posts[email]</email>
</cliente>
XML;
```

Comment: For some reason, now the error now marks where the post variables are

Comment: Well you fixed the first error so it has now moved on to the next one. There you go, Jay has fixed the next error for you already

Comment: Amm where? Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Ricardo Rios: Please see the updated anwer, it wasn't precise earlier. Try to understand the error message that is given. PHP error messages are not always perfect (to say at least) but they give some hints :)

Comment: I see now, for some reason now is changing the < > tags of the xml to this &lt; like nombre&gt;PRUEBA&lt;/nombre&gt; instead of <nombre>PRUEBA</nombre>

Comment: @RicardoRios: Whatever you do :) - Perhaps it's time to use an XML library instead of doing string-concatenation your own?

Comment: @hakre when I used something like $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);  the cliente tag dissapears like magic, do you know any other library?

Comment: it does not. use view-source of your browser. it will magically re-appear :) (remember: browser displays HTML, so removes tags. for your browser the XML looks like HTML it can't interpret)